# Collapsing sublayers in legend in Print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

Does anyone know how can I collapse the legend items (subgroups) in the printing layout in QGIS?

[image]

I found some link here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html

but nothing is about it, what I want. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation you linked, see: Use the <kbd>addGroup</kbd> button to add a legend group.